# Student loans paid already but collection agency claiming loans are in default

Tags: united-states, irs, student-loan, debt-collection

I paid off my student loans via pay garnishments and the IRS taking 3 to 4 years of my tax refunds.

Unfortunately, I have moved 5 times in last 2 years and I cannot find my files confirming this.

After a few years of finally getting my tax refunds, a  collection agency contacted me, saying that I still have loans in default.

I told them that I paid these off and they said prove it. 
Now they are taking my tax refund because I couldn't prove it and everybody associated with this loan - including the IRS - supposedly can't find anything.

What should I do? They collected over what I owed. Please help.

Comment: Are they _actually_ taking your tax return or _threatening_ to take it? Collections agents can be very sly about making threats to scare you into sending them money.

Comment: "I tell them I paid these off and they said prove it." The burden is on them to prove it. Demand [verification of debt](https://www.alllaw.com/articles/nolo/bankruptcy/debt-verification.html).

Comment: They can't just "take your tax return". There are several steps in which you could respond before they're able to take anything. The last of them is a judge signing an order.  If you're in court that day you could surely ask them to provide proof of the debt.